# OPC client creates another instance of OPC server

Tags: c#, opc

I have created OPC server using OPC Graybox.

When I launch this as a console application, everything is fine - multiple clients can connect and read the data from this sever.

However, the problem happens when the server is hosted within Windows Service. 
When OPC client connects to OPC server, it creates another one instance of Windows Service and that does not fit me.

I found one workaround here: http://support.ge-ip.com/support/index?page=kbchannel&id=09237d4900112023bed2600678f
But, after choosing of 'Interactive user' on Identity Tab of the OPC Server, I need to reboot the service in order to apply the changes. And as soon as service is rebooted, Identity tab reverts back to the 'Launching user', so I didn't have to chance to check this solution.

Any ideas how to overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

"Interactive User" is usually not a good choice either. For OPC servers, and especially those that should run as Windows service, a specific, concrete user should be chosen. Try it. If such setting also keeps reverting to something else. then - to my knowledge - it is probably the server doing it itself, so you need to fix it; Windows does not do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to:

1. on the PC where the OPC server is installed go to the dcom settings (by launching dcomcnfg command);
2. select your OPC server from the list  and open the properties panel;
3. select the *Identity* tab;
4. if checked, uncheck the *Run application on this computer* element;

See this image as example:
[Disabling *Run application on this computer* in the *Identity* tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8QPb.png)

This worked for me.